# Hive - Converting a string to bigint

Tags: hive, hiveql, data-conversion

Suppose I have a string like `'00321'` and I want to convert it into a `BIGINT` in Hive, how would I do it?

Follow-up question: would the resulting `BIGINT` value be `321` or `00321`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `CAST` function to cast your `STRING` to a `BIGINT`, like so:

```
SELECT CAST('00321' AS BIGINT) FROM table;
```

As a `BIGINT` it will show on the screen and in delimited text files as `321`.